# how to close web view in flutter on button click

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I am working on flutter app where i redirect to web view for certain operation and after the operation is success on a button click i want to come back to app by closing the web view. Giving `navigator.pop()` on button click is not closing the web view, it just navigate back to previous page in web.any solution for this issue. attatching my web view and final success page with this.

```
class PlansWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String token;
  const PlansWebView({Key key, this.token}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlansWebViewState createState() => _PlansWebViewState();
}

class _PlansWebViewState extends State<PlansWebView> {
  bool isLoading = true;
  bool _dstReached = false;
  WebViewController _webViewController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _dstReached ? Navigator.pop(context) : print('plans web view page');
    print(widget.token);
    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      WebView(
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onPageFinished: (finish) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
        },
        initialUrl:
            'my webview link',
        onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) =>
            _webViewController = webViewController,
        navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
          if (request.url == 'webviewlink/#/signin') {
            setState(() {
              _dstReached = true;
            });
            Navigator.pop(context);
            // do not navigate
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          }

          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ),
      isLoading
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            )
          : Stack(),
    ]);
  }
}
```

below is the code where i have put a button and on that button click i want to close web view.

```
class Success extends StatefulWidget {
  Success({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SuccessState createState() => _SuccessState();
}

class _SuccessState extends State<Success> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    addPayment(addPaymentFields);
    final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          EmptySection(
            'assets/images/success.gif',
            'Successful !!',
          ),
          SubTitle(
            'Your payment was done successfully',
          ),
         ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: COLORS['PRIMARY_COLOR']),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                        context, '/signin', (route) => false);
                  },
                  child: Text('Sign In')
)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget SubTitle(String subTitleText) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 16.0),
    child: Text(
      subTitleText,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18.0,
        color: Color(0xFF808080),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget EmptySection(emptyImg, emptyMsg) {
  return Center(
      child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Image(
        image: AssetImage(emptyImg),
        height: 150.0,
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
        child: Text(
          emptyMsg,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            color: Color(0xFF303030),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ));
}
```